# Unable to build Project in eclipse due to ".svn" folder

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am not able to build project which I have imported from "SVN" repository.

Issue: There is a project on which I have to work on, which I need to import from svn repository. I have imported("Open Project from File System") the Project folder from svn repository but on refreshing Project, it shows error as

```
The project was not built due to "Could not delete '/Hybrid Framework/bin/.svn'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent
```

My research: This issue is happening due to ".svn" folder exists in the SVN repository, due to which Eclipse is unable to build the Project.

I tried hiding ".svn" folder from Properties but it didn`t worked.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without dipping into the depths of Eclipse (and it's SVN integraton)

If you can't build due to `.svn` folder (i.e you have project imported from Working Copy) you have, obviously:

Import project, **which doesn't have** this folder

You can achieve it at least by two ways

- Move|delete `.svn` folder outside tree
- Create unversioned tree from Working Copy (svn help export) and import this clean project

Comment: 1st way is the one I am using now as I couldn`t figure out the proper way.

Comment: The proper way is that `.svn` must exist within every source folder, but **not** within output folders. The reason is obvious: You should not check-in nor check-out compiled files, but just source files.